# Is SAML still a viable option for single sign on java applications?

Tags: java, spring-boot, single-sign-on, saml

I can't find an open source SAML library that doesn't include several dependencies riddled with vulnerabilities.  Every reference or example code I find is outdated or referencing packages that no longer exists or open source no longer supported (ie. opensaml3, spring.security.opensaml, etc).  Everything after 2019 seems not to work.  Is SAML dead?

Comment: There is native spring security support for SAML2 https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/saml2/index.html. According to the description of [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/saml2/login) example, SAML2 support was introduced in Spring Security 5.2.0 (Oct 1, 2019) and SAML Logout support was added in version 5.6.0 (Nov 17, 2021)

Comment: No, it's not dead. Still used by many corporates. I presume you looked at the options here? - https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43

Comment: According to the Spring team, they decided to discontinue the effort to create a library on top of another library, and opted to instead provide framework support.  According to this git, the project is not even stable at this point.  All research leads me to believe it's a bad idea to use what Spring provides in any ad-hoc way.  Thank you for the additional docs, though!

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml#spring-saml

Comment: @rbrayb unfortunately, nothing published before 2021 seems to reference any support libraries that are not deprecated or riddled with vulnerabilities.  that article was from 2018, so almost definitely not current.  Appreciate the comment, though!